# не происходит UPDATE в бд

Tags: php, mysql, update

Итак. Здравствуйте.

в phpmyadmin следующий код проходит:

```
UPDATE letPhone SET name =  '123',number =  '1244121',description =  '124124' WHERE id =  '55'
```

Запрос через сайт выглядит так -

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    mysqli_query(
        $connection, 
        "update  'letPhone' 
            SET 
                'name'='" . ($_POST['name']) . "',
                'number'='" . ($_POST['number']) . "', 
                'description'='" . ($_POST['description']) . "'
            WHERE 
                'id'= '" . ($_POST['id']) . "'"
    );

    echo 'Изменение сохранено';

}   else {
    echo 'не срослось!';
}
```

var_dump - следующий

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> string(4) "123" ["number"]=> string(7) "1244121" ["description"]=> string(6) "124124" ["id"]=> string(2) "55"
```

И получается что данные с предыдущей страницы я получаю.
но запрос на изменение ячеек в бд не проходит. По вардампу видно что все 4 переменные есть.

Подскажите что я не так делаю и почему запрос не проходит?
[сама сраница](http://vhost20229.cpsite.ru/numberPeople.php)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0, http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: эм... если я правильно понял Вы просто пробелы и табуляцию проставили?

Answer (score -1):

```
"update  `letPhone` 
SET 
`name`='".($_POST['name'])."',
`number`='".($_POST['number'])."', 
`description`='".($_POST['description'])."'
WHERE 
`id`= '".($_POST['id'])."'"
```

Comment: Дайте развернутый ответ. Поясните, что вместо `'` надо `\`` ! Расскажите про SQL Injection...

Comment: @E_p , Опять 25.
Если человек учится, то зачем перегружать его тонкостями, типа иньекций и PDO? Пусть себе вникает потихоньку. Со временем все найдет и поймет, а не поймет - жизнь научит.

Comment: В данном случае, это не блажь. Приложение написанное этим человеком скорее всего попадет в продакшн. И им возможно воспользуетесь вы. И ваши личные данные уплывут. Если взялись учить, то учите качественно.